# Difference between RestSharp methods AddParameter and AddQueryParameter using HttpGET

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to call an external API.

This works:

```
var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);
var request = new RestRequest(myurl, Method.GET);

foreach (var param in parameters)
{
    request.AddQueryParameter(param.Key, param.Value);
}
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

This doesn't:

```
var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);
var request = new RestRequest(myurl, Method.GET);

foreach (var param in parameters)
{
    request.AddParameter(param.Key, param.Value);
}
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Resulting in:

> System.Exception: API Call MyWebAPIMethod GET: Failed with status code
>   0 - Unable to connect to the remote server

What's the difference between `AddParameter` and `AddQueryParameter`?

According to the documentation they should function the same when using HttpGET and according to Fiddler they seem to generate the same URL as well.

Comment: Why doesn't the 2nd not work.  Do you get an error?

Comment: Most likely code above is unrelated to error you have. What url are you trying to GET?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**To answer your question**

`AddQueryParameter` adds a parameter in the query string as `ParameterType.QueryString` whereas `AddParameter(string, object)` adds the parameter as `ParameterType.GetOrPost`

For more details on each parameter type, see:

`GetOrPost`: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest#getorpost

`QueryString`: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest#querystring

**To solve your problem**

It seems it is unrelated to the type of parameter, because the exception thrown seems to indicate you aren't even connecting to the remote server.

make sure you pass the same `apiUrl` / `myUrl` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP and anyone else who might have trouble with the concept.
It took me awhile to get around to the concept.
You probably need to visualise the RESTful standard of how to construct a GET request message in a url against constructing for a POST request message.

You will notice that for GET , the parameter(s) are attached to the URL header
whereas for the POST , the parameter(s) are placed in the body of the message.
RestSharp 's method AddQueryParameter() will only add the (Query) parameters in the header of the message, whereas the AddParameter() will only add the parameters to the mesasge body. As demonstrated below the GET has one query parameter with a value of "Flavours" . For the POST , the parameters contact_name and company_name are located in the bottom of the message body.

### Eg:

**GET message format :**

GET http://www.consumerdiarydemo.cbrnetwork.test.au/api/ConsumerDiary/getSizesOrFlavours/Flavours HTTP/1.1
Host: www.consumerdiarydemo.cbrnetwork.test.au
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://www.consumerdiarydemo.cbrnetwork.test.au/ConsumerDiaryPage2template
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

---

**POST message format :**

POST 
http://localhost:1234567/api/customers HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

{"contact_name":"value_data1","company_name":"value_data2"}

Answer (score 0):

**AddParameter / Get or Post**

`GetOrPost` behaves differently based on the method. If you execute a GET call, RestSharp will append the parameters to the Url in the form `url?name1=value1&name2=value2`.

On a POST or PUT Requests, it depends on whether you have files attached to a Request. If not, the Parameters will be sent as the body of the request in the form `name1=value1&name2=value2`.

Ref: https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#get-or-post

**AddQueryParameter / Query String**

`QueryString` works like `GetOrPost`, except that it always appends the parameters to the url in the form `url?name1=value1&name2=value2`, regardless of the request method.

Ref: https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#query-string