# RestSharp - Does .AddParameter add to the Header or the Body for a POST request?

Tags: c#, rest, api, restsharp

Trying to determine if RestSharp's `AddParameter` method adds the parameter to the body or the header of the request for Method `POST`.

```
            var request = new RestRequest("/token", Method.POST);

            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", client_id);
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", client_secret);
            request.AddParameter("username", username);
            request.AddParameter("password", password);
```

If it sends in the header, our API calls will begin to fail due to an upcoming change to the API provider.

How do I determine this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestSharp provides a separate `AddHeader` method for adding data to the request headers, as demonstrated in sample in the [readme](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/README.md).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643093/difference-between-restsharp-methods-addparameter-and-addqueryparameter-using-ht) `AddParameter` will add the parameter with the [`GetOrPost`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest#getorpost) type, which will add query parameters if it is a GET request, or add items to the request body if it is a POST request.

The source for the `AddParameter` method where you provide a parameter name, and a parameter value is available [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L430-L444) and you can see that the passed in type is `ParameterType.GetOrPost`.

For posterity the source currently is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add the parameter to the request
/// </summary>
/// <param name="p">Parameter to add</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IRestRequest AddParameter(Parameter p) => this.With(x => x.Parameters.Add(p));

/// <summary>
/// Adds a HTTP parameter to the request (QueryString for GET, DELETE, OPTIONS and HEAD; Encoded form for POST and PUT)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">Name of the parameter</param>
/// <param name="value">Value of the parameter</param>
/// <returns>This request</returns>
public IRestRequest AddParameter(string name, object value)
    => AddParameter(new Parameter(name, value, ParameterType.GetOrPost));
```

As an extra bit of information the source for the `AddHeader` method is available [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L546-L554), along with [the documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest#httpheader) on how these `HttpHeader` parameter type is handled.

Comment: I also verified this is true using webhook and sent a dummy request